# How to change the cursor theme in CLI?

Tags: terminal

I want to change the cursor to be block-shaped.

[image]

All applications (nano,vi,vim,…) should should have a square-style cursor like the picture above.

Comment: That depends on the terminal emulator, not the applications (though applications could fake a cursor after telling the terminal to hide its own, I'm not aware that any does, and not all terminals can be told to hide their cursor)

Comment: yes，but my question is in the command line interface,not in GUI@Stephane Chazelas

Comment: You may want to be more specific than _command line interface_. The command line typically displays and takes input from a terminal (physical, or emulated like `xterm`, the Linux virtual consoles, or other X or non-X based ones). I've got the suspicion that you're talking about Linux standard virtual VGA consoles, which is what @tdk2fe's answer covers.

Comment: Change to `zsh` - that example if from `zsh`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The cursor is drawn by the terminal or terminal emulator, not the applications running within them. Some of them have provision to allow the user to change the shape or attributes of the cursor using escape sequences.

Changing the cursor shape independently from the type of the terminal can be done using the `cnorm` (normal cursor), `civis` (cursor invisible), or `cvvis` (cursor very visible) terminfo capabilities (for instance using the `tput` command). However, it doesn't give you any warranty that any of `cnorm` or `cvvis` will be a *block* cursor.

To affect the blinkiness, shape and colour and behaviour of the cursor specifically, that will have to be done on a per-terminal basis.

On Linux on x86 PCs VGA and frame buffer virtual consoles, it can be controlled [using escape sequences](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/vga-softcursor.html) like:

```
printf '\e[?x;y;zc'
```

In the simplest form:

```
printf '\e[?xc'
```

You define the height of the cursor where `x` ranges from `1` (invisible cursor) to 8 (full block), `0` giving you the default (currently, same as `2`).

So:

```
printf '\e[?8c'
```

will give you a full block cursor.

Actually that's what `tput cvvis` sends (while `tput cnorm` sends `\e[0c` and `civis` `\e[1c`).

When using the 3 parameter form, the behaviour will vary with the underlying video driver. For instance to get a sort of grey non-blinking block cursor as your question suggests, you'd do:

```
printf '\e[?81;128;240c'
```

In a PC VGA Linux console. And:

```
printf '\e[?17;30;254c'
```

In a frame buffer Linux console.

Now, that was Linux specific, other terminals have different ways to change the cursor shape. For instance `xterm` and `rxvt` and their derivatives use the same sequences as the VT520 terminal to set the cursor shape:

```
printf '\e[x q'
```

Where `x` takes a value from 1 to 6 (from [xterm manual](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)):

- 0  -> blinking block.
- 1  -> blinking block (default).
- 2  -> steady block.
- 3  -> blinking underline.
- 4  -> steady underline.
- 5  -> blinking bar (xterm).
- 6  -> steady bar (xterm).

And the colour can be set with:

```
printf '\e]12;%s\a' 'colour'
```

So your grey steady block cursor could be achieved there with:

```
printf '\e[2 q\e]12;grey\a'
```

For most X11 terminal emulators, you can also change the cursor attributes via command-line options to the command that starts the emulator or via config files or X11 resources, or menus.

For instance, for `xterm`, you have  the `-uc/+uc` option for *underline cursor*, `-ms` for its colour, and `cursorBlink`, `cursorColor`, `cursorOffTime`, `cursorOnTime`, `cursorUnderLine`, `alwaysHighlight` resources to configure it.

And the default menu on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left click has an option to turn blinking on or off.

Comment: thanks! `echo -e '\e]12;red\a'` works in terminal emulator: xterm, terminator, kitty..

Comment: @yurenchen, that prints an extra new line. See also [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: thanks for your reply, 
I know `printf` is easier to handle, but `echo` word is easy to read and write.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, the current version of *a*ge**tty** (contained in `util-linux 2.27.1` [util-linux is the linux package providing most core commands, like `login`, `su`, `mount`, `more`, `kill` - to name a few] - and you should have it if your linux kernel version is >=4.4) has a different behavior than described in the yet-to-be-updated kernel.org documentation ([Software cursor for VGA](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/vga-softcursor.html)).

Consider

`echo -n -e '\e[?`*byte1*`;`*byte2*`;`*byte3*`c'`

byte1:

```
+---------------+---------------+
|  high nibble  |   low nibble  |
+---+-----------+-----------+---+
|msb|           |           |lsb|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                  |   |   |   |
                  |   |   |   +-+
                  |   |   |     |   These bits specify the 8
                  |   |   +-----+-> possible  blinking HW caret
                  |   |         |   
                  |   +---------+
                  |
                  +---------------> When set, this bit enables SW
                                    caret instead of HW caret
```

byte2 (SW caret):

```
                +-----------------> A pretty useless mask applied
                |                   to bits in byte3
+---------------+---------------+
|  high nibble  |   low nibble  |
+---+-----------+-----------+---+
|msb|           |           |lsb|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

byte3 (SW caret):

```
+---------------+---------------+
|  high nibble  |   low nibble  |
+---+-----------+-----------+---+
|msb|           |           |lsb|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  |   |   |   |
  |   |   |   +-------------------> Highlighting
  |   |   |
  |   |   +---------------------+
  |   |                         |
  |   +-------------------------+-> Color
  |                             |
  +-----------------------------+
```

Highlighting: highligths the character beneath the caret (e.g. changing it to white [true shiny white] instead of dark white [the light gray that is commonly the default for TTYs]).

Color: the color of the caret. Note that, compared to the usual order of ANSI color codes we all know and love, bits are reversed, so -for this triplet- the 7th is the **l**sb while the 5th is the **m**sb.

So, while in the 70s ANSI defined the following color codes, setting a *de-facto* standard adopted universally for TTYs, miscellaneous linux terminals, consoles, and whatnot

```
0 black
1 red
2 green
3 yellow or dark yellow
4 blue or dark blue
5 magenta, purple or violet
6 cyan or light blue
7 white or dark white (light gray)
```

in this case we have the opposite

```
7 white or dark white (light gray)
6 cyan or light blue
5 magenta, purple or violet
etc.
```

So, here comes the list:

```bash
#Hardware carets (blinking and [dark ]white)
echo -n -e '\e[?0c' #default caret
echo -n -e '\e[?1c' #invisible caret
echo -n -e '\e[?2c' #underscore caret
echo -n -e '\e[?3c' #thicker underscore caret
echo -n -e '\e[?4c' #smaller block caret
echo -n -e '\e[?5c' #small block caret
echo -n -e '\e[?6c' #big block caret
echo -n -e '\e[?7c' #biggest block caret
#On my Linux machine, both 6 and 7 are the big rectangular full-size block caret

#Software carets (non-blinking and colored)
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;0c'  #00001000 0 00000000 black (thus invisible on black background)
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;128c'#00001000 0 10000000 red
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;64c' #00001000 0 01000000 green
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;192c'#00001000 0 11000000 yellow
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;32c' #00001000 0 00100000 blue
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;160c'#00001000 0 10100000 magenta
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;96c' #00001000 0 01100000 cyan
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;224c'#00001000 0 11100000 dim white
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;16c' #00001000 0 00010000 black     + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;144c'#00001000 0 10010000 red       + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;80c' #00001000 0 01010000 green     + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;208c'#00001000 0 11010000 yellow    + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;48c' #00001000 0 00110000 blue      + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;176c'#00001000 0 10110000 magenta   + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;112c'#00001000 0 01110000 cyan      + highlighting
echo -n -e '\e[?16;0;240c'#00001000 0 11110000 dim white + highlighting
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command from the prompt, or add it to your login scripts:

`echo -e '\033[?6c'`

Escape sequences are used to control output formatting in the terminal.  `echo -e` says to interpret escape characters - in this case \033 is interpreted as an ESC sequence (033 is the ASCII code for ESC).  The [ANSI Escape Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) can control everything from blink rate, color, and other aspects of the terminal output.

Comment: Note that there's nothing ANSI about that specific sequence. It's Linux specific, details [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/VGA-softcursor.txt)