# Howto change the cursor symbol to a unicode special character?

Tags: terminal-emulator

I want to change my terminal cursor symbol to a blinking, orange "lambda-sign", how can I do that? I don't want to change PS1 or anything at the prompt, but the cursor shape and behaviour itself.

Google wasn't a real help with this issue.

I am using yakuake-term, but I would want to change every cursor I can find on my system to the blinking lambda sign / any unicode character.

Comment: You're going to have to specify your terminal emulator at least.

Comment: Related: [How to change the cursor theme in CLI?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115009)

Answer (score 3):

According to a [KDE page](https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/utils/yakuake/repository)

> Yakuake is a drop-down terminal emulator based on KDE Konsole technology.

In other words, it uses Konsole.  The [source-code for Konsole](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/applications/konsole/repository) in [Enumeration.h](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/applications/konsole/repository/revisions/master/entry/src/Enumeration.h#L80) defines three cursor styles for the *terminal*:

```
enum CursorShapeEnum {
    /** Use a solid rectangular block to draw the cursor. */
    BlockCursor     = 0,
    /** Use an 'I' shape, similar to that used in text editing
     * applications, to draw the cursor.
     */
    IBeamCursor     = 1,
    /** Draw a line underneath the cursor's position. */
    UnderlineCursor = 2
};
```

Unlike other terminals (see [How to change the cursor theme in CLI?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115009/how-to-change-the-cursor-theme-in-cli)), Konsole controls its cursor shape (as well as whether the cursor blinks) via *profiles*.  You can change profiles via a dialog.  Konsole also (see *[How to set cursor to blinking in Konsole from script or vim?](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=227&t=126004)*) recognizes an escape sequence which alters profile settings.

For example, this sets it to the block cursor:

```
printf "\033]50;CursorShape=0\007"
```

None of the enumerated choices supported by Konsole are "***orange "lamda-sign"***".

Other terminal emulators have different methods for setting the cursor shape.  Very few (if any) provide a *character* for the text-cursor.

Most terminal emulators in X provide a *mouse pointer*, also referred to as a *cursor theme*.  You can set almost any image for those (even colored).  But those do not blink.  See for example

- [Cursor themes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cursor_themes) (Arch wiki)
- [How to change mouse cursor and theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66843/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-and-theme)